# Custom Barcode scanner, cannot pass back scanned data

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

I am having trouble passing back data that is scanned by my custom barcode scanner. 
The data is read successfully and I am able to assign the value to a variable. But I cannot pass the data back to the previous view controller to populate a text view.

I am using this below to pass to my barcode VC to store the data inside it

```
var barcodeScanData: String = ""
```

I am using prepare for segue below to

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BarcodeScanVC" {
        let desitnationVC = segue.destination as! BarcodeScanVC
        desitnationVC.xyz = barcodeScanData
    }
}
```

Below here is where I am attempting to send back the data from my custom barcode scanner

```
var xyz: String = ""

func launchApp(barcodeScan: String) {

        if presentedViewController != nil {
            return
        }

        let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Barcode Found", message: "\(barcodeScan)", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let barcodeData = PartsVCDetail()
            self.xyz = barcodeScan
            barcodeData.barcodeScanData = self.xyz
            print(self.xyz, "This is what I am sending")
            print(barcodeData.barcodeScanData, "This is what I am sending it TO" )


            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)

        alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertPrompt.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The two print lines

```
print(self.waybill, "This is what I am sending")
print(barcodeData.barcodeScanData, "This is what I am sending it TO"
```

Show me the correct scan data, however, when I use the last line below:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

The data is lost and I see an empty value in my viewDidAppear on the first view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print(barcodeScanData, "This is empty but it shouldnt be")
    dataFromBarcodeScanner.text = barcodeScanData
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code `let barcodeData = PartsVCDetail()` you are creating a new instance of `PartsVCDetail` and then setting the property of that instance.  As soon as the action ends this instance will be deallocated and you will return to the previous view controller via `popViewController`.

A common solution to your requirement is a delegation pattern.

- You declare a protocol for your delegate to implement
- You have the original view controller implement this delegate protocol
- You have the original view controller set itself as the second view controller's delegate
- The second view controller can invoke the delegate method to pass the data back

**Protocol**

```
protocol BarcodeScanDelegate {
    func didScan(barcodeData: String)
}
```

**PartsVCDetail**

```
class PartsVCDetail: UIViewController, BarcodeScanDelegate {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let desitnationVC = segue.destination as? BarcodeScanVC {
            desitnationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func didScan(barcodeData: String) {
        self.barcodeScanData = barcodeData
    }
}
```

**BarcodeScanVC**

```
var delegate: BarcodeScanDelegate?

func launchApp(barcodeScan: String) {

    guard presentedViewController == nil else {
        return
    }

    let alertPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Barcode Found", message: "\(barcodeScan)", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.delegate?.didScan(barcodeData: self.xyz)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil)

    alertPrompt.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertPrompt.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer, but can you clarify the protocol portion?

Comment: A protocol defines an interface that an object can conform to.   So your first view controller adopts and implements the protocol. The second view controller can use any object that conforms to that protocol a server it's delegate; it doesn't need to know the exact type of the delegate object.  As long as the delegate implements the protocol it must have the `didScan` function.  There is a whole chapter in the Swift book from Apple on protocols

Comment: awesome yes thank you I did some research on it. 
Where you have destinationVC.delegate = self this line is not working for me..

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"? - Do you get an error?  What error?

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'PartsVCDetail' to type 'BarcodeScanDelegate?'

Comment: then i do this self as! BarcodeScanDelegate, and it gives warning  Treating a forced downcast to 'BarcodeScanDelegate' as optional will never produce 'nil'

Comment: You need to make sure you have added `BarcodeScanDelegate` to the `class PartsVCDetail` line as per my answer.  You don't need a forced cast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187145/discussion-between-paulw11-and-julian-silvestri).